# iOS "the new iPad" UIDeviceHardware hw.machine codename

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

So, I have the following code "machine names" for the current lineup of iOS devices.  Does anyone know with some certainty what the codes for "the new iPad" is?  (iPad announced Mar 7, 2012)

```
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return @"iPhone1G GSM";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return @"iPhone3G GSM";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    return @"iPhone3GS GSM";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return @"iPhone4 GSM";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"])    return @"iPhone4 CDMA";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])    return @"iPhone4S";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"])    return @"iPhone5";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      return @"iPod 1G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      return @"iPod 2G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      return @"iPod 3G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])      return @"iPod 4G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])      return @"iPad WiFi";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])      return @"iPad2 WiFi";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])      return @"iPad2 GSM";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])      return @"iPad2 CDMAV";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,4"])      return @"iPad2 CDMAS";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return @"Simulator";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"x86_64"])       return @"Simulator";
```

Comment: Apple doesn't know?  (developer.apple.com)

Comment: No. Apple has not officially released this that I can find. However, there are people that have gone into the innards of Xcode and the IOS released dmg's that always find what these are.  I am not one of them, so i asked.

Comment: This is not NDA-covered.  It is plain and simple code -- just like anyone would ask (and indeed has asked and gotten answers to in the past)  Just because it is not officially documented does not mean it is NDA-covered

Comment: I'm looking into it, will get back to you...

Comment: Apple is probably going to treat it like "The new coke" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Coke

Comment: How about putting that values into a NSDictionary instead of using that 200 if-statements? And where did you buy that iPhone5?

Comment: What about iPad mini and the new iPod touches and iPad 4G?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iClarified [states](http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=8500) three new iPad3 models as:

5.1.0 (iPad 3 Wi-Fi): iPad3,1

5.1.0 (iPad 3 GSM): iPad3,2

5.1.0 (iPad 3 CDMA): iPad3,3

They have links to restore images on apple.com, so the info might not be too far off.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. iPad3,3 = iPad 3 (GSM) ( source; the device I am holding in my sweaty fingers :D )

Comment: This is actually incorrect: the `iPad3,3` is the global version of the GSM/CDMA model; the non-global being `iPad3,2`. See [The iPhone Wiki](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=iPad_3).

Answer (score 10):

Updated!  Using [iPhone Wiki](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models).

```
- (NSString *) platformString{
    NSString *platform = [self platform];
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return @"iPhone 1G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return @"iPhone 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    return @"iPhone 3GS";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return @"iPhone 4";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,2"])    return @"iPhone 4 CDMA";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"])    return @"Verizon iPhone 4";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])    return @"iPhone 4S";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"])    return @"iPhone 5 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,2"])    return @"iPhone 5 (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 1G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 2G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 4G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod5,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 5G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])      return @"iPad";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])      return @"iPad 2 WiFi";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])      return @"iPad 2 GSM";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])      return @"iPad 2 CDMA";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,4"])      return @"iPad 2 CDMAS";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,5"])      return @"iPad Mini Wifi";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"])      return @"iPad Mini (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,7"])      return @"iPad Mini (GSM + CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"])      return @"iPad 3 WiFi";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"])      return @"iPad 3 CDMA";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"])      return @"iPad 3 GSM";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,4"])      return @"iPad 4 Wifi";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,5"])      return @"iPad 4 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,6"])      return @"iPad 4 (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return @"Simulator";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"x86_64"])       return @"Simulator";
    return @"Unknown";
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was disappointed to see `iPad3,4` on the iPad 4 instead of what I expected (`iPad4`!)

Answer (score 1):

Now, I checked.
iPad mini Wi-Fi: iPad2,5

Answer (score 0):

[UIDeviceIdentifier](https://github.com/squarefrog/UIDeviceIdentifier) maintains a full map between hw.machine codename with platform string.