# Programmatically detect whether an iPad has Retina display?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

How can I programmatically (Objective-C) whether an iPad has a Retina display?

Comment: Why? In general you should detect and adjust for _features_ rather than specific devices.

Comment: @StephenDarlington - My application is only for iPad, and the new iPad  has a bigger resolution. I just need to add on code the new values for screen resolution.

Comment: @Freedom - You don't have to code differently for the new iPad. The frames and positioning of your views will not be changed. If you have images, simply add `@2x` versions of them that have double dimensions but your code will not change, there are only new image files to add.

Comment: I have a viewcontroller that is build programmatically (depends on the data received from web service). This viewcontroller, has a UITableView controller, and i would like to add some more information on UITableViewCell for the new iPad (because has a bigger screen resolution, so has more space).

Comment: @Freedom It doesn't really have more space. The screen is still the same size physically. 10pt text is still 10pt in size. People's fingers are still the same size.

Comment: @StephenDarlington This is going beyond the scope of the topic, but e.g: if I have a UILabel from 0 to 300 (...CGRectMake(0, 300, 300, 50)) and other from 300 to 700 (...CGRectMake(300, 700, 300, 50)), on iPad 3 I will have free space on the right side? or I am doing a big confusion because of the resolution of the screen?

Comment: @Freedom No, you won't have free space on the right side. It will be the same as on the iPad 2, though the text will be sharper.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad && [[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] && [UIScreen mainScreen].scale > 1)
{
    // new iPad
}
```

Comment: While technically correct, it will most likely return true for all the future iPads as well (which still may be just what you need).

Comment: This answers the question, (detect Retina display).  But if you really need to know device version, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638970/ios-the-new-ipad-uidevicehardware-hw-machine-codename) for an answer which identifies _all_ devices.

Answer (score 5):

As other posters have answered, you should check for features rather than models. However, in the few obscure cases where you might want to identify a particular model, you can use the hw.machine sysctrl as follows. Note that if you can't identify the model, it's most likely because your code is running on a new model, so you should do something sensible in that case.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

// Determine the machine name, e.g. "iPhone1,1".
size_t size;
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0); // Get size of data to be returned.
char *name = malloc(size);
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", name, &size, NULL, 0);

NSString *machine = [NSString stringWithCString:name encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
free(name);
```

Now you can compare "machine" against known values. E.g., to detect iPad (March 2012) models:

```
if ([machine hasPrefix:@"iPad3,"]) NSLog(@"iPad (March 2012) detected");
```

Comment: I already tested my app on iPad(Retina) emulator and it worked. I thought that I would have a problem because of the new resolution of the new iPad, but I was totally wrong. Thanks anyway, this can be useful for others.