# How to Identify the new iPad

Tags: ios

I need to know current device is iPad2 or new iPad. 
I use `[[UIScreen mainScreen] Scale]`,but the result is 1.0

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically detect an iPad 3 (HD)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688930/programmatically-detect-an-ipad-3-hd)

Comment: build your app with xcode 4.3 with 5.1 SDK - this way you should get scale 2.0 for iPad3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688930/programmatically-detect-an-ipad-3-hd):

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad && [[UIScreen mainScreen]     respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] && [UIScreen mainScreen].scale > 1)
{
    // new iPad
}
```

Comment: this method is not effective. new ipad scale also 1. and thank you your answer.

Comment: the new ipad scale is 2.0. You don't need to check for `respondsToSelector` since he's looking at iPad 2 and the new iPad, which means it always have `scale` property

Comment: @spmno - I can confirm that the `scale` property returns 2.0 on the new iPad in all of my applications, so it is a viable check. Note that you need to be building with the iOS 5.1 SDK for this to work.