# iPad 2/ Retina iPad, how does the app identify which device it is running on?

Tags: ios

I'm trying to figure out how an app knows which version of an Idevice it is on? I know how to separate iPhone and iPad within a universal app, but what about the difference between device versions I.e. ipad2, retina iPad. What if I'd like to tell an app it's on an ipad2 and not retina iPad as to not use the retina version of the game or to give the user a choice to pick which version they would pre

Comment: Duplicate Question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108859/detect-the-specific-iphone-ipod-touch-model ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically detect an iPad 3 (HD)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688930/programmatically-detect-an-ipad-3-hd)

Answer (score 3):

If you care about screen scale you can check if `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] > 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can work this out from the resolution on the device, `Retina` devices have a resolution twice the size of none `Retina` devices :)

Comment: This is true for now but may not always be true, you should use the method mentioned by @kevboh to determine this.