# Kobold2d how to detect an ipad3

Tags: kobold2d, ipad-3

Hi I am trying to work out how to run a universal app in Kobold2d.

I would like to have graphics designed for 320x480, 640,960. to support the iPhones.
Just to repositions it for the iPad 1 & 2.

And not to use the iPad 3 (new) high resolutions?

So far if I enable Retina support it does for all devices.

Can it be restricted?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688930/programmatically-detect-an-ipad-3-hd  … when you detect iPad 3, disable Retina mode. But you'll disappoint iPad 3 users with low resolution images.