# What's the value of hw.machine for iPhone5?

Tags: iphone

I used **uidevice-extension** to get the device type before. This is the value for iphone5 in **uidevice-extension**:

```
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"])    return @"iPhone5";
```

I am not sure if the the value for iphone5 is correct since it is updated before the release date of iphone5. Thanks for any information!

Comment: Maybe this link would help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638970/ios-the-new-ipad-uidevicehardware-hw-machine-codename

Comment: Thanks  @Gill , I just updated my question. I am not sure if the value for iphone5 is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iPhone 5 GSM - iPhone5,1

iPhone 5 CDMA - iPhone5,2

iPod 5 - iPod5,1

Info taken from the iOS file names. Please check http://osxdaily.com/2012/09/19/ios-6-ipsw-direct-download-links/